# Installing package via Ansible using a user with limited sudo rights

Tags: ansible, sudoers

I have access to a CentOS box to a non-privileged user with limited sudo rights, i.e. `/etc/sudoers`

```
dummy ALL=(root)  NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/yum, /bin/rpm
```

Several roles in my deployment playbook install software using yum, an extract of a task could be as following:

```
---
- name: failing example 
  hosts: servers
  remote_user: dummy

  tasks:
    - name: Install prerequisite packages
      yum:
        pkg: git
      state: present
      become: true
```

running this task leads to the following failure:

```
TASK [Install prerequisite packages] ****************************************
fatal: [xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to xxx.xxx closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

running `sudo yum install git` on the remote host as user dummy works like a charm. Any idea how to fix this problem? I guess that ansible probably is not calling the system program directly and hence the sudoer config does not apply.